# Is there anyway to use environment variables in static scope?

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I want to set a static variable with using environment variables.
Is there anyway to achieve this?

---

I'm trying to get BUILD_URL from static variable like this.

```
class CustomEnvironment {
  static String CUSTOM_ENV = BUILD_URL.contains('stg') ? 'STG' : 'PROD'
}
```

---

*Error Message:*

> Apparent variable 'BUILD_URL' was found in a static scope but doesn't refer to a local variable, static field or class. Possible causes:
>   You attempted to reference a variable in the binding or an instance variable from a static context.
>   You misspelled a classname or statically imported field. Please check the spelling.
>   You attempted to use a method 'BUILD_URL' but left out brackets in a place not allowed by the grammar.
>   　static String CUSTOM_ENV = BUILD_URL.contains('stg') ? 'STG' : 'PROD'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No. You can't.**

It is the basic property. It will work if the `BUILD_URL` also be a `static` variable. But here it is not....

So you can achieve this in this way,

```
class Test{
    static String getCustom(String val)
    {
        return val.contains('stg') ? 'STG' : 'PROD'
    }
}

println Test.getCustom('test')
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just wanted to make it sure that there is no way to get Environment Variables in static scope.

Comment: @tonarimochi glad it helped.. ! Enjoy Learning : )